# How are LLMs assigned tasks in Python code?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, large-language-model

I'm following Nicholas' Renotte's tutorials on VSCode, LangChain, and OpenAI using Python.

These are the codeblocks I've seen from the aforementioned tutorials, and I don't see any other lines of code that tell the AI what to do.

```py
title_template = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables = ['topic'],
    template='write me a youtube video title about {topic}'
)
```

So is AI given a task using this kind of conversational language? Is that really all that's needed, and wouldn't this place a lot of pressure on precise wording of the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The template (`write me a youtube video title about {topic}`) is called a prompt template, and the only difference between such a template and an actual prompt (like the ones you give to ChatGPT for instance) is that prompt templates are formatted strings: `{topic}` gets substituted by something else. It is true that the wording of the assignment is important - writing good prompts has become something of a domain in itself, called 'prompt engineering' ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering#:~:text=Prompt%20engineering%20(also%20known%20as,of%20it%20being%20explicitly%20given.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering#:%7E:text=Prompt%20engineering%20(also%20known%20as,of%20it%20being%20explicitly%20given.)). If you want to learn more about generative AI and large language models, I would recommend taking a look at Cohere's free LLM University: https://docs.cohere.com/docs/llmu